# Lift: Refresh/Reload Snippet

Tags: scala, lift

i'm using an AjaxSelect which contains several ids. By selecting an id the additional information to this id should be displayed in a given table which will be generated by a snippet. Now i want to know which would be the best solution to refresh my list?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="lift:MainScreen.cars">
            <td><car:name /></td>
            <td><car:type /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**SCALA:**

```
def doSelect(msg: NodeSeq) = {
  SHtml.ajaxSelect(cars.map(i => (i.no.toString, i.no.toString + ". Car")),
    Empty, {
      selectedCar =>
        controller.chooseCar(selectedCar.toInt)
        // RELOAD TABLE
    })
}

def cars(node: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
  val cars = controller.chosenCarFamily.cars
  cars match {
     case null => Text("There is no items in db")
     case game => game.flatMap(i =>
       bind("car", node,
            "name" -> car.name,
            "type" -> car.type))
  }
}
```

Comment: In the function cars, isn't it `i.name` instead of `car.name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [ValueCell](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/net/liftweb/util/ValueCell.html) and [WiringUI](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/net/liftweb/http/WiringUI%24.html). Very good examples can be found at [simple_wiring](http://demo.liftweb.net/simple_wiring)  and [invoice_wiring](http://demo.liftweb.net/invoice_wiring).

When using `WiringUI`, each time the valueCell `cell` is updated, the content linked with `WiringUI.apply(cell)` will be updated. So it should do the trick.

Here is an example for your specific case:

**HTML:** 
Same as yours

**SCALA:**

```
class MainScreen{
  def doSelect(msg: NodeSeq) // same as yours

  def cars = WiringUI.apply(controller.chosenCarFamily)(displayResult)

  def displayResult(carFamily:CarFamily)(node: NodeSeq) ={
    carFamily.cars match {
      case null => Text("There is no items in db")
      case game => game.flatMap(i =>
        bind("car", node,
          "name" -> i.name,
          "type" -> i.type))
    }
  }
}

object Controller{
  val selectedCar = ValueCell(1)
  def chooseCar = sectectedCar.set      
  val chosenCarFamily = selectedCar.lift(car:Int => //Stuff to output the family)
}
```

Comment: I know that my code is not perfect, mainly in the "displayResult" function, so if you have any suggestion comment or edit my answer.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your reply and with the apply method it works, but in fact i don't think this solution is the best match for my problem. Because i commit the chosen id in `controller.chooseCar(selectedCar.toInt)` which saves the id in a model and i want to get the chosen Car by use the method `controller.chosenCar` so i would work with two variables which contains the same id which is needless.

Comment: Maybe you can put the valueCell in controller? I don't have the total view of your project but basically, as soon as you have a valueCell somewhere, it will work.

Comment: The problem is as follows: When i select an item from the selectbox, the corresponding id will be commited to the model by the controller. The model saves a "CarFamily" object, which includes a list of cars. When i use `controller.chosenCarFamily` i want to generate a list of all cars within the CarFamily object and this list should be updated by the chosen item of the selectbox.

Comment: Maybe you can try and have a look at the function `lift` in `ValueCell`to generate a Cell[List[Car]]. 
If you want a more complete solution, can you add a kind of `controller` in your code so I can see what you are really doing?

Comment: I added my `cars` method in my post. Maybe now you understand what i do!

Comment: For my solution you will need to add some `ValueCell` in your `controller`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7175/discussion-between-chrisjamesc-and-siggy-petersen)

Comment: Yes, the problem is that i use one controller for several views (console, gui) so i'm not allowed to change the controller.

Comment: In this cas I don't know, I hope a more suitable solution will come.